# How do I disable line numbers in an Octopress codeblock?

Tags: octopress

I see some Octopress sites that have no line numbers in their codeblocks. How do you do that? Is there some attribute in `{% codeblock %}` tag? Or do I have to modify the codeblock plugin source?

Answer (score 2):

Using blockquotes through 4 space indentation should do what you're looking for, but it'll be without syntax highlighting.

If you're fine with losing line numbers everywhere, you can modify `plugins/pygments_code.rb` and remove the bit of code that generates line numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to just update the CSS to not display the gutter?

Comment: You're absolutely right. You can modify the CSS to achieve the same visual effect (though you'll still have them there in the HTML). 

`pre.line-numbers { display: none; }` should do it.

Comment: Can you provide an example... I'm not sure if you mean the blockquote should be first or the indent should be first.

Answer (score 1):

A patch for `pygments_code.rb` as suggested by bilalq above (sorry, too big to fit in the comments of his answer)

```
--- a/plugins/pygments_code.rb
+++ b/plugins/pygments_code.rb
@@ -29,11 +29,11 @@ module HighlightCode
     end
     highlighted_code
   end
+
   def tableize_code (str, lang = '')
-    table = '<div class="highlight"><table><tr><td class="gutter"><pre class="line-numbers">'
+    table = '<div class="highlight"><table><tr>'
     code = ''
     str.lines.each_with_index do |line,index|
-      table += "<span class='line-number'>#{index+1}</span>\n"
       code  += "<span class='line'>#{line}</span>"
     end
     table += "</pre></td><td class='code'><pre><code class='#{lang}'>#{code}</code></pre></td></tr></table></div>"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **kramdown markup engine**, it comes with an option you set in your `_config.yml` file, `coderay_line_numbers`:

```
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  use_coderay: true
  coderay:
    coderay_line_numbers:
    coderay_css: class
```

It can be set to `nil` (as in this example), `inline`, `table` or `list`. Maybe the blogs you have been seeing without line numbers use this method.

You can see some **screenshots** of the different options in my [blog post](http://blog.alestanis.com/2013/02/04/octopress-and-the-twilight-color-scheme/) about kramdown in Octopress.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add:

```
pre.line-numbers { display: none; }
```

to `sass/custom/_styles.scss`.

*This is from a comment on one of the answers by @bilalq , but I think it's the best, simplest, and most sane answer around (sane as in you want to keep your customizations under `sass/custom/`).*

Comment: In my case I added a file with the CSS code you mention in `sass/theme-name/custom/`